# Unzip (Info-ZIP) Permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, zip

Is there a way to invoke unzip (from Info-ZIP) on a Linux system without having it restore the permissions stored in the zip file? The zip files I'm restoring are enormous, so going back over the contents with something like "chmod -R" will take a while. I do not control the source of the archives, so my only choice is to handle the permissions on extraction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restoring permissions is a feature of `unzip` (from the `man` page, version 6.00):

```
Dates,  times  and  permissions of stored directories are not restored
except under Unix. (On Windows NT and successors, timestamps  are  now
restored.)
```

and there is no option to switch if off.

It might be that an older version of `unzip` did not support restoring permission, but investigating that route is probably more cumbersome than trying to change the latest `unzip` source to do what you want.

If running `chmod -R` is unacceptable you can take a look at using Python's [zipfile library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html), it is easy to use and gives you full control over the way you write the files that you extract from the zip file.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39296577/1307905) for how to make sure ZipFile restores attributes.